# List styling, CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I want to select only the first child(list item) of ordered list, which I did using.

`.ci-content ol.my-list > li:first-child{
color:green; //selected item in green..
}`

[check the problem here](http://codepen.io/Durai/pen/zrmqWp?editors=1100)

Can I achieve the same without using "my-list" class in the selector?...how do I restrict the depth of selection.

Note: I can have ol anywhere, not immediately inside '.ci-content' always.

```html
<ol class="my-list">First set
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one  </li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  </ol>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <ol class="my-list">Second Set
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two</li>
      <ol>
        <li>three.two.one</li>
        <li>three.two.two</li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: `.ci-content ol li{padding:15px} .ci-content ol:first-child{padding:20px !important}`

Comment: @JimishGamit, This was helpful. I have reframed my question.  Can I achieve the same without introducing class. Check the codepend..

Comment: [my suggestion](http://codepen.io/anthu/pen/pgQvdY?editors=1100)

Comment: @anton  your solution worked...brilliant..